# Twitter, facebook, and bitly analytics

Tags: database, facebook, twitter, analytics, bit.ly

im working on a project that collects analytics from twitter, facebook, and bitly API.  I was wondering what was the best type of data base i should be using for this to be efficient.  Mysql? nosql? mongodb?  i'm open to anything.  Will be doing this in rails framework.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's question which will have subjective answers. My answer would be always MySql